# Returning Json of byte array in web api c#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, asp.net-web-api2

Hi I have developed a `Web API` in which I am taking some parameters in URL and then processing them. The protocol I am using is `Modbus`. It returns a byte array and in return, I want to get some specific string data from it. Below is my code

```
  public string GetData(int slaveId, int dataAddress, int registerCount)
    {

        //string hexValue = intValue.ToString("X");
        // Convert the hex string back to the number
        int slaveHex = int.Parse(slaveId.ToString("X"), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        int addressHex = int.Parse(dataAddress.ToString("X"), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        int countHex = int.Parse(registerCount.ToString("X"), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);


        //serial port settings and opening it
        var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM2", 9600, Parity.Even, 8, StopBits.One);

        serialPort.Open();

        var stream = new SerialStream(serialPort);
        stream.ReadTimeout = 200;
        // send request and waiting for response
        // the request needs: slaveId, dataAddress, registerCount            
        var responseBytes = stream.RequestFunc3(slaveHex, addressHex, countHex);

        // extract the content part (the most important in the response)
        var data = responseBytes.ToResponseFunc3().Data;         

        //Convert a byte array to string
        var stringFromByteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
        serialPort.Close();

        return stringFromByteArray;
    }
```

The `data` contains an array of 14 bytes

[image]

The `stringFromByteArray` returns the following

```
"\0�\0�\0�\0\u0016\0\u0017\0\u0018\0\u001a"
```

As you can see in above the returned string is not as expected. I want exact values as in data byte array.

The resulting output I want it to be in `Json response`. Like below

```
{
  [0] => "220",
  [1] => "230",
  [2] => "240", 
  [3] => "22",
  [4] => "23",
  [5] => "24",
  [6] => "26",
}
```

How can I do it? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Well then, a simple linq chain should give you the expected result: `var result = data.Where(r=>r>0).Select(r=>r.ToString()).ToArray()`

Comment: And what will you expect when the even indexed values in the array are different from 0. For example, what will you expect when you have values like `[220,255,140,255]`?

Comment: @Eldar the first index value will be always 0

Comment: @Eldar the resulting response is not in `Json` like I want

Comment: Then you something like this: `var result = data.Where((r,i)=>i % 2 == 0).Select(r=>r.ToString()).ToArray()` And If you want a json result just serialize result array into json.

Comment: can you share what the value of `data` looks like?

Comment: also, from the documentation of modbus, can you post the encoding that is uses to send the data to your application.

Comment: @Saravanan I have already attached an Image

Comment: @Saravanan the sending of data is perfectly alright and the response is ok. I just want to convert into `Json` as I mentioned in my question

Comment: also I want to mention the array size will be different depending upon the address and count I have sent

Comment: As mentioned in the below answer, it is not valid to consume the byte[] as such, the API might be encoding the data and sending you in bytes, you have to get hold of the library and understand how to get the right response or how to parse the response in a right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From broad perspective, there are several options available to you.

First off, you might consider using `application/octet-stream` as the response type instead of `application/json` in the HTTP response. `application/octet-stream` means bytes are directly sent over HTTP. This is how you'd usually upload/download files.

Secondly, it is possible to encode binary data into text in safer manner, e.g. using encoding algorithms such as [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), which you can achieve in .NET using [Convert.ToBase64String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=netstandard-1.0) method. Such methods are more verbose than using `octet-stream` but also play better when attempting to send structured data with some binary contents.

And finally, as you requested, you can use a structure to represent the data directly. There are several options, you can encode an array of numbers directly, which would yield you JSON payload as:

```
[220, 230, 240, 22, 23, 24, 26]
```

To achieve this, you simply serialize a list of numbers, e.g. `byte[]` directly or possibly `int[]` based on the behavior of your serializer (.NET Core 3.0+ System.Test.Json.JsonSerializer converts byte arrays to base64 so conversion to `int[]` is needed). [Live sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KWh2uh).

The structure you requested is not directly possible in JSON, but you can achieve something similar serializing a `Dictionary<string, string>`, yielding a structure of `{ "0": "220", "1": "230", "2":"240" ... }`. Note, however, that this structure is quite verbose and not very practical.

You can get the dictionary using the following snippet:

```
var bytes = new byte[] { 220, 230, 240, 22, 23, 24, 26 };

var dictionary = bytes
    .Select((b, i) => (value: b, index: i)) // convert bytes to sequence of (byte value, index)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.index.ToString(), x => x.value.ToString());
```

Comment: Ok finally while returning how can I return it? as I could not use `return dictionary` simply

Comment: You should just return the dictionary all the way up to your controller, either on its own or as a part of the controller's return type.

Comment: If you can't change the return type of the method in question, I don't see any other way than using the base-64 encoding or directly serializing into json, but I believe the second case would land you in more trouble as your controller would double-encode the response unless you're doing something special. I think changing the methods signatures would be easier but I don't have the full context of your project to cerrectly advise.

Comment: I want to return a json response so I can consume it at server end

Comment: Yes, so what happens when you change the `GetData` method signature to return `Dictionary<string, string>`? Do you get a compiler error somewhere else? Can you change that somewhere else to also return `Dictionary<string, string>` and so on until you get no compiler errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211466/discussion-between-zdenk-jelinek-and-faisal).